# Using Proxy with mobx Store

Tags: javascript, proxy, mobx, mobx-react

I have an application with react and mobx and I want to separate all logging user interaction (actions call ) from the Mobx store so I do some search and I found that proxy pattern is the best way to this staff and my question is how I can work with Mobx and proxy in my case.
thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [**spy**](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/spy.html) for this purpose.

**Example ([JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/sesuqedexo/edit?js,console))**

```
class Store {
  @observable count = 1;
  @action
  increment(step) {
    this.count = this.count + step;
  }
}

const store = new Store();

setInterval(() => store.increment(store.count), 1000);

spy((event) => {
  if (event.type === 'action') {
    console.log(`${event.name} with args: ${event.arguments}`);
  }
});
```